# Compound adjective

Tags: adjectives, compounds

I know a compound adjective can consist of a noun and a participle. But, sometimes the meanings of compound adjectives confuse me.  What's the difference of noun with present participle and noun with past participle? How to use them?

Eg:Data-transferred hard drive, Data-transferring hard drive

Answer (score 1):

If you use a present participle, as a part of the complex adjective, it means you want to describe that this word is referring to the process, a subject of the sentence is a part of.

Here is an example.

**This drive is involving into the data-transferring process.**

Using a past participle implies that the subject (or the object) of the sentence is rather the result of the previous action.

Here is another example.

**This process depends on several newly-transferred parameters.**

Comment: So, data-transferring hard drive can mean a hard drive perparing for data transferring or a hard drive is doing data transferring. And, data-transferred hard drive can imply a  hard drive that has been transferred the data into. Did I get that,right?

Comment: Yes, data-transferring hard drive is just receiving or sending data (or it’s quite ready for receiving or sending), being an active part of the current data-transmission. But data-transferred hard drive could be like a current storage of the data, since this data has been transferred into this drive just before the moment of speaking or maybe a bit earlier, of course.